Can a probable cause statement be used on two different people after the first charge on a person is dismissed
The incident occured a month before any charges were issued.The incident involved Joe Smith Jr,the officer detained Joe Smith Jr and ended up just making Joe Smith Jr sign a no trespassing order.A month later Joe Smith father Joe Smith Sr got a summands in the mail with a court date and a battery charge.the probable cause affidavit was the officer statement from the incident involving Joe Smith Jr,but the affidavit list Joe Smith dose not refer to Joe Smith Jr or Joe Smith Sr just Joe Smith with Joe Smith Sr date of birth,social security number driver license number and address.The charges were dropped on Joe Smith Sr on his court date.But Joe Smith Jr was then served with a Warrant for his arrest,and battery charges but his probable cause affidavit is the exact same officer statement and still list Joe Smith with Joe Smith Sr identifiers.Shouldnt the probable cause affidavit have to list  Joe Smith Jr and his correct identifiers.or vice versa when charges were filed on Joe Smith Sr when the incident didn't involve him to begin with?Indiania

I am having a very difficult time following this question (which seems to be the intent). Regardless, can you please clean up the grammar to help ensure that your intent is more clearly conveyed?

@Pyrotechnical, what makes you assume intent, considering that no policeman or judge would be expected to consult stackexchange on this? Writing coherent texts is hard and it requires practice.

@o.m. I'm assuming it was the querent's intent that the party's be confusing and thus easy to make some sort of clerical error. I'm not assuming anything about criminal intent.

As I understand your question, an affidavit did make the clerical error of mixing John Smith Junior and John Smith Senior.
The clerical error was corrected some but not all documents. Such an error should be corrected, but failure to correct it does not usually invalidate the legal proceedings. There are precedents e.g. to allow search warrants to stand in such a situation.

Sorry I can see this site is not for me.  I figured ethier Joe Smith Sr or Joe Smith jr's should not been found and issued.

It's not the right site if you want to hear what you want to hear. Mistakes can be made, and mistakes that are not fixed can have legal consequences.

@Alicia, are you asking what the law is, or arguing what it should be? The error was corrected and the charges against Senior were dropped. The lawyer for Junior can argue in court that the error gives reasonable doubt as to the identity of the perpetrator, but further testimony would likely remove this doubt.

A probable cause statement says that charges should be pressed against someone. It is not needed. A mistake in it has no bearing.
Charges are brought through an indictment or information.

This is not even an answer to the question asked.

@trish how is it not? The person asked if the wrong name being put on a probable cause statement meant they could not be charged.
